# Removing one of two ggplot legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble figuring out why ggplot gives two legends. I would like the legend title "Resampling Technique" but I prefer the legend icons in the bottom legend. How can I adjust my code to accomplish this? I thought removing either the group or colour arguments might fix this but it did not work.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(textConnection(
  'Obs misclass  IR      resample
  1  0.134466667   1      Original
  2  0.123200000   2      Original
  3  0.097706667   4      Original
  4  0.065955556   8      Original
  5  0.041427451  16      Original
  6  0.024301010  32      Original
  7  0.013343590  64      Original
  8  0.007186563 128      Original
  9  0.139200000   1         Smote
  10 0.134733333   2         Smote
  11 0.137426667   4         Smote
  12 0.135103704   8         Smote
  13 0.131972549  16         Smote
  14 0.132014141  32         Smote
  15 0.131394872  64         Smote
  16 0.132234625 128         Smote
  17 0.137133333   1 Undersampling
  18 0.136555556   2 Undersampling
  19 0.135893333   4 Undersampling
  20 0.138703704   8 Undersampling
  21 0.138607843  16 Undersampling
  22 0.138365657  32 Undersampling
  23 0.135341538  64 Undersampling
  24 0.139755556 128 Undersampling
  25 0.142733333   1        Hybrid
  26 0.136600000   2        Hybrid
  27 0.137640000   4        Hybrid
  28 0.136044444   8        Hybrid
  29 0.132800000  16        Hybrid
  30 0.133644444  32        Hybrid
  31 0.134152821  64        Hybrid
  32 0.132190698 128        Hybrid'), header = TRUE)


   hw <- theme(
  plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5,face='bold',size=23),
  axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0,vjust=.5,face='bold',size=23),
  axis.title.x=element_text(face='bold',size=23),
  plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=0.5),
  plot.caption=element_text(hjust=-.5),

  strip.text.y = element_blank(),
  strip.background=element_rect(fill=rgb(.9,.95,1),
                                colour=gray(.5), size=.2),

  panel.border=element_rect(fill=FALSE,colour=gray(.70)),
  panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
  panel.spacing.x = unit(0.10,"cm"),
  panel.spacing.y = unit(0.05,"cm"),
  axis.ticks=element_blank(),
  axis.text=element_text(colour="black"),
  axis.text.y=element_text(margin=ggplot2::margin(0,3,0,3),face="bold",size=20),
  axis.text.x=element_text(margin=ggplot2::margin(-1,0,3,0),face="bold",size=20),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"),
  legend.title=element_text(face="bold",size=23),
  legend.text=element_text(size=20,face="bold"),
  legend.title.align=0.5
)


ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(IR), y=misclass, colour = as.factor(resample),group=as.factor(resample))) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) +
  geom_point(shape=24,size=3,aes(color=as.factor(resample),fill=as.factor(resample))) +hw+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,0.15,0.025))+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=2^(0:7),labels=c("1","2","4","8","16","32","64","128"))+
  labs(x="Imbalance Ratio",y="Risk")+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Resampling\nTechnique"))
```

Comment: Remove `,fill=as.factor(resample)` and `+hw` from you code. It will give you only one legend.

Comment: Whoops, I completely forgot to include the `hw` object in my code. I'd like to keep that. Removing fill makes the triangles transparent but I'd like them to remain filled.

Comment: I just included `fill=FALSE` in `guides()` which removes the legend but the icons are still transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(IR), y=misclass, colour = as.factor(resample),group=as.factor(resample))) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) +
  geom_point(shape=24,size=3,aes(color=as.factor(resample),fill=as.factor(resample)), show.legend = F) +hw+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,0.15,0.025))+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=2^(0:7),labels=c("1","2","4","8","16","32","64","128"))+
  labs(x="Imbalance Ratio",y="Risk")+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Resampling\nTechnique"))
```

I have added `, show.legend = F` in `geom_point` to remove the extra legend.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the points in the legend, you only need to change the last `guides`:

```
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Resampling\nTechnique"), color=FALSE)
```

---

[image]